# As fit as an animal

Tags: idiom, phrase-request, animals, finnish

If someone is in good health, one can say that they are as fit as a flea (or fiddle) in English or as healthy as a billy goat ("terve kuin pukki") in Finnish.
What would be a similar idiom in Latin, indicating excellent health?
I would prefer an animal comparison if there is one, and in any case something more colorful than *optimae valetudinis*.

(To make this easier to find, let me repeat the key question in Finnish: Miten sanotaan "terve kuin pukki" latinaksi?)

Comment: I have never seen such an expression. We English also say 'fit as a butcher's dog', maybe _validus sicut lanii catellus_

Comment: Hmm. Latin tends toward the concrete rather than the metaphoric, so my guess is that unfortunately *optimæ valetudinis* is probably the best choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am trying to find more examples, but for the present I can add one to the exhibit. It is likely that this is *not* an established idiom.

From [Plauti *Fragmenta*](https://books.google.com/books?id=qCBVAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA1742):

> Quasi lupus ab armis valeo.

The footnote of the above edition glosses this irregular use of *ab* as specifying *how* the speaker is strong, i.e. "**I am as strong as a wolf in my shoulders.**" (N.B. [*armus, -i*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Darmus) = shoulder.)

This almost definitely refers to *strength and ferocity* rather than *health*. Compare to other usages with the same animal:

> Quasi lúpus esuriens ille metui ne in me faceret impetum. (Plautus, *Captivi* 912)

Comment: Perhaps there was no perfectly matching idiom in Latin, but "as strong or ferocious as a wolf" is close enough for now. Thanks! (I will have to unaccept if someone finds a better fit later. I don't want to keep anyone from giving another answer.)